# Read and write stereo .wav file with python + metadatas

Tags: python, audio, scipy, signal-processing, wav

What's the easiest way to read and write a **stereo** .wav file in Python ?
Should I use `scipy.io.wavfile.read` ?

- Should I use a 2-dimension array (how ?) in order to have `x[n,j]` where `j` is the channel number?
- I also want to read/write  metadatas stored in the wav file like the `markers`, `MIDI root note` (Soundforge, as well as other sound editors, can read/write this specific .wav metadata called "MIDI root note")

Thank you

PS : I already know how to do with a mono file :

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
(fs, x) = read('test.wav')
```

Comment: do you know a trick for reading stero .wav files ?  
I don't how to handle it ? 2-dimensional array ? something else?

Comment: how to deal with 2 channels ?

Comment: http://www.swharden.com/blog/2011-07-08-create-mono-and-stereo-wave-files-with-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an updated version of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds:

- 24 bit .wav files support for read/write,
- access to cue markers,
- cue marker labels,
- some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.

[wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)

---

*Old (original) answer: a solution for only a part of the question (ie read stereo samples):*

```
(fs, x) = read('stereo_small-file.wav')
print len(x.shape)         # 1 if mono,    2 if stereo
# if stereo, x is a 2-dimensional array, so we can access both channels with :
print x[:,0]
print x[:,1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Pythons' wave module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see how to read/write the `MIDI root note` metadata with Python's wave module, do you know how is this possible ?

Comment: No. I don't know, sorry.

Comment: I have the same question for "markers" metadatas that can be included in WAV file