# ValueError: only 1-dimensional arrays can be used

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

```
import scipy
from matplotlib.pyplot import specgram
sample_rate,X = scipy.io.wavfile.read("a3.wav")
print(X.shape)
specgram(X,Fs=sample_rate,xextend=(0,30))
```

i am new to python . and first time use python for audio processing . and have struct on following problem . please help .
i want to plot the spectrogram for a wave file. 
In above code sample of python I got following Output:

```
(528038, 2)
ValueError: only 1-dimensional arrays can be used
```

Comment: I think your question is actually answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118343/2454357)

Comment: Thanks for point to right direction