# Scipy.io.wavfile.read() returned data

Tags: python, audio, scipy

I'm currently learning to work with audio and i don't understand the scipy.io.wavfile.read() function. What does each element array returned by the function represent? Is it the sample's amplitude or something else? This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117228/data-returned-by-scipy-io-wavfile-read) but it didn't really get an answer about this, just answer on why is it a 2d array, which i already know. 
And why is the size bigger than expected. I have the code

```
import scipy.io.wavfile

samplerate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read('violin.wav')

print(samplerate)
print(data.shape)
```

with the output

```
48000
(2013211, 2)
```

My 'violin.wav' is 41 second, with the sampling rate of 48000, the data' shape should be should 1968000, why is it 2013211?

Comment: According to the return value, your WAV file is actually 41.94189583333... seconds long. You say it is 41 seconds--how do you know this? Perhaps some other software that displays the duration is truncating the reported length to an integer?

Comment: oh i haven't thought of that, maybe that's the reason.